# Rails endless pagination - undefined local variable

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination, infinite-scroll

I have **UsersController** and in this controller I am loading users' posts, something like this:

```
def welcome
  @postss = Post.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
  render 'users/show'
end
```

Then in **users/show.html.haml**

```
#posts
  = render 'posts/index', :posts => @postss
  = will_paginate @postss
```

In **users/show.js.erb**

```
alert('a');
$('#posts').append('<%= j render('posts/show') %>');
<% if @postss.next_page %>
    alert('c');
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@posts) %>');
<% else %>
    alert('c');
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```

The problem is, that when I load the page, I see in the console this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `post' for #<#<Class:0x007ff707e647d0>:0x007ff726648d98>):
```

But I am not able to detect what is the problem - I put into the JS file `alert` messages, but dont' pop up... I would be grateful for every  advice.

Thanks a lot

**EDIT:**
I followed [this topic](https://gist.github.com/adamrobbie/4066325). The difference in my code is, that in the block **index.html.erb** I use **@postss** instead of **@posts**, because this variable is empty (I don't know if it's a typo on the gist)

Comment: wrong instance variable...should be @postss as you stated in the controller

Comment: provide please controller show method

Comment: Hi Joe, you mean `posts/show` or `users/show`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In **users/show.js.erb**

```
$('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@posts) %>');
```

you used the wrong variable name there! replace with **@postss**?

Comment: I've tried it, but there is still the same error. When I scroll down, I see just "Fetching data..." and in the log `undefined local variable or method 'post' for...`

Comment: Also, the error in logs points to this line: `$('#posts').append('<%= j render('posts/show') %>');`

Comment: so you are not passing the "post" variable to the show template where you are using it

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `users/show.js.erb`

```
$('#posts').append("#{escape_javascript(render(:file => 'posts/show.html.haml'))}")
<% if @postss.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(@posts) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
```